# Is it okay to ask HR if I can keep a company issued headset and how much that would take out from my backpay?

Tags: resignation, equipment

I just sent in my two-weeks notice but I was wondering if I could keep the company-issued headset (I work in a call center). I think I would be okay with them deducting the cost of the headset from my backpay depending on how much it would be. I really like the headset because the audio quality is decent, and I don't really know how to choose good-quality headsets so it would be a bit of a hassle for me to research and buy a new one.

I can't ask my manager because I feel like he's mad at me for resigning (and his replies to most of my questions have been pretty short/cold, but that might just be me). I also don't know if I can ask HR how much they'd deduct from my backpay if I kept it (like idk if that's rude or if that would leave a bad mark on my record?).

A friend suggested that I just file it as lost or broken. But it's highly unlikely I would lose it (working from home) and I feel like if I say it's broken they'd ask me to send it back anyway.

I checked our employee handbook and it didn't really specify anything about headsets. But the most relevant bit of info on there was the part that said (not verbatim) if a company-issued thing is lost or broken, and they feel like it was lost/broken because of the employee's negligence, the employee will shoulder the cost to repair or replace it.

This is my first time ever to resign so I have no idea how any of this works. Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want to just ask, can't you read the model number from the headset and order a pair for yourself?

Comment: I don't have the box anymore; I left it in the office and I'm not really able to go back to check because of COVID. I tried looking up the brand (no info about the model on the actual thing) but I couldn't find a model that looks like it.

Comment: The answer really seems to be just to ask your manager/HR because we don't know company policy. If they don't allow it, they would probably still tell you the brand and model number if you asked.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try that.

Comment: You can always ask, just expect to be told "no". Also, your IT department should have all the information you need to procure a set for yourself in the event the answer isn't positive.

Comment: HR are the wrong people to ask. Ask your ex-manager.

Answer (score 18):

Just ask.

Chances are they are not reusing the headset anyway. Body worn devices tend to be "personal" and cleaning and disinfecting a headset for resuse is often cost prohibitve especially in Covid times. By taking it off their hands, you may actually safe them the cost of disposing it properly.

Comment: I was coming to say pretty much this. When I was issuing headphones like this at my last job, I considered them "fully utilized" the minute I handed them to a staff member. It's not worth the liability or the morale of the "ick factor" to try to re-use them.

Answer (score 4):

Things like headsets really shouldn't be reused - considering the long-term skin contact and the likelihood that cleaning them well enough to pass on to someone else will damage them (airlines got around this pre-COVID by replacing the covers, and they're used for a much shorter time by any one individual).

Chances are pretty good the headset will just be disposed of - and some jurisdictions would require environment safe disposal because of the plastic and electronic components, which might cost money.

So, there's no harm in asking. But I'd ask first without mentioning money - you might just be able to keep them for free. If they want you to pay a nominal amount for them, they'll let you know.

In either event - make sure you get a piece paper from them that says they gave the headset to you, just in case your boss somehow decides you simply took them.